# Selectively forward email based on domain?

Tags: linux, email, procmail

I have an alias on my mail server, call it `splitusers`.

Based on which domain (a couple are run off one mail server) is used, I would like the mail forwarded to a different user account.

Eg:

> `splitusers@first.tld` should forward to `firstuser@first.tld`
>   `splitusers@second.tld` should forward to `seconduser@second.tld`

How can I accomplish this? Is <kbd>[procmail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procmail)</kbd> the right approach? If so, what would the recipe look like?

Comment: Which mail server are you running? How is it configured?

Comment: @derobert - postfix .. not sure what you mean by "how is it configured"

Answer (score 1):

Procmail can be used to do this, but will need and Envelope-to header added by the MDA.

It may be simpler to setup virtual domain aliases in the mail server.  `Exim4` supports different aliases for different domains, but needs some setup to do so.  I would expect this capability from Postfix and Sendmail as well, although I haven't multiple domains with them.